# WebRTC file transfer and syntax querySelector

Tags: javascript

i never use WebRTC. so do not have any understand how their syntax look like.
i got a couple of syntax which i think it is not jquery. so anyone mind to tell me is it specific to webRTC related code.

```
document.querySelector('#stop-recording').onclick = function() {
        this.disabled = true;
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.stream.stop();
        document.querySelector('#pause-recording').disabled = true;
        document.querySelector('#start-recording').disabled = false;
    };
```

what is `querySelector` ?

i got the code from this url https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder/blob/master/demos/video-recorder.html

looking for bit info. thanks

Comment: http://google.com/?q=document.queryselector

Comment: querySelector has nothing to do with webrtc. To use WebRTC in the browser you just use JavaScript, it doesn't have to do anything with the syntax, it's just another API. Please try to be more specific in your question, don't just paste code here.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer following code:

```
var audio_context;
                        var recorder;
                        $(function () {
                            try {
                                //Audio Recording 
                                window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
                                navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                                        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                                        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                                                        navigator.msGetUserMedia);
                                window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                                var recorderObject;
                                var VM_IDForAudio = "";
                                var audio_context = new AudioContext;
                                var localMediaStreamForAudio;
                                var audioStream;

                                //Audio-Video Recording (Firefox)
                                var videoFile = !!navigator.mozGetUserMedia ? 'video.gif' : 'video.webm';
                                var inner = document.querySelector('.inner');
                                var videoElement = document.getElementById('webcamVideo');
                                var VM_IDForAudioVideo = "";
                                var localMediaStreamForAudioVideo;

                                //Disable Live Webcam Button
                                $("#btnShowWebcam").prop("disabled", true);
                            } catch (e) {
                                //alert('No web audio support in this browser!');
                                console.log("No web audio support in this browser!");
                            }

                            //Audio Recording
                            $("[id$='btnAudioRecord']").click(function () {
                                //VM_IDForAudio = $("[id$='hdVMID']").val();
                                VM_IDForAudio = $("[id$='hdPRN']").val() + "_" + $("[id$='hdVMID']").val() + "_" +
                                    patientDet.visitType + "_" + replateDateString(patientDet.visitDate);
                                $this = $(this);
                                $recorder = $this.parent();
                                if ($("[id$='btnAudioRecord']").val() == "Record Audio") {
                                    if (VM_IDForAudio != "") {
                                        $this.attr("value", "Stop Record");
                                        navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, function (stream) {
                                            if (window.IsChrome) stream = new window.MediaStream(stream.getAudioTracks());
                                            audioStream = stream;
                                            recorder = window.RecordRTC(stream, {
                                                type: 'audio'
                                            });
                                            recorder.startRecording();
                                        }, function () { });
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        //Select Patient 
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $this.attr("value", "Record Audio");
                                    if (recorder)
                                        recorder.stopRecording(function (url) {
                                            var reader = new window.FileReader();
                                            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                                            reader.onloadend = function () {
                                                base64data = reader.result;
                                                PageMethods.SaveAudioRecording(base64data, VM_IDForAudio);
                                                audioStream.stop();
                                            }
                                        });
                                }
                            });

                            //Audio-Video Recording
                            $("[id$='btnAudioVideoRecord']").click(function () {
                                //VM_IDForAudioVideo = $("[id$='hdVMID']").val();
                                VM_IDForAudioVideo = $("[id$='hdPRN']").val() + "_" + $("[id$='hdVMID']").val() + "_" +
                                    patientDet.visitType + "_" + replateDateString(patientDet.visitDate);
                                $this = $(this);
                                if ($("[id$='btnAudioVideoRecord']").val() == "Record Aud/Vid") {
                                    if (VM_IDForAudioVideo != "") {
                                        $this.attr("value", "Stop Record");
                                        captureUserMedia(function (stream) {
                                            window.audioVideoRecorder = window.RecordRTC(stream, {
                                                type: 'video', // don't forget this; otherwise you'll get video/webm instead of audio/ogg
                                                canvas: {
                                                    width: 320,
                                                    height: 240
                                                }
                                            });
                                            localMediaStreamForAudioVideo = stream;
                                            $("#btnShowWebcam").prop("disabled", false);
                                            window.audioVideoRecorder.startRecording();
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        //Select Patient 
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $this.attr("value", "Record Aud/Vid");
                                    $("#btnShowWebcam").prop("disabled", true);
                                    window.audioVideoRecorder.stopRecording(function (url) {
                                        convertStreams(audioVideoRecorder.getBlob(), videoFile, VM_IDForAudioVideo);
                                    });
                                    localMediaStreamForAudioVideo.stop();
                                }
                            });
```

and use RecordRTC javascript library.
for more go through this: http://recordrtc.org/RecordRTC.html,
for live demo: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/AudioVideo-on-Firefox.html

Answer (score 1):

you should check [webtorrent](https://github.com/feross/webtorrent) github repository, there is a detailed description about webRTC and how it is implemented. also check out the [webtorrent official website](https://webtorrent.io/)